# How to update style of selected item inside ViewPager?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-viewpager

I want to update the style of the selected item inside a ViewPager.
How can I do this?

[image: Design 1]

This is the UI design. As you can see, the "November" tab is selected, so the corresponding bar is highlighted in yellow.

The way I've implemented this is a ViewPager with a custom item (white, not highlighted):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="142dp"
        android:layout_height="275dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/monthly_spend_month"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/December"
            android:textColor="@color/aluminum"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="34dp"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/monthly_spend_card"
            android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="155dp"
            android:background="@drawable/monthlyspend_card_bg_inactive">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/monthly_spend_text"
                android:textColor="@color/almost"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
                android:text="Total
                spent"
                android:textSize="@dimen/balanceDescTextSize"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/monthly_spend_amount"
                android:textColor="@color/almost"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/monthly_spend_text"
                android:text="$ 254.98"
                android:textSize="@dimen/balanceDescTextSize"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I plan on doing the highlighting programmatically.

Here's some adapter code:

```java
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.monthlyspend_item, container, false);

        TextView monthlySpendMonth, monthlySpendAmount;

        monthlySpendCard = view.findViewById(R.id.monthly_spend_card);
        monthlySpendMonth = view.findViewById(R.id.monthly_spend_month);
        monthlySpendAmount = view.findViewById(R.id.monthly_spend_amount);

        monthlySpendMonth.setText(monthlySpendings.get(position).getMonth());
        monthlySpendAmount.setText(monthlySpendings.get(position).getAmountSpent());

        container.addView(view, 0);

        return view;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you should change your model (in your case "monthlyspendings") at the selected item position.

then notify the adapter

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

and finally, custom selected view according to the model. for exapmle :

```
if(monthlySpendings.get(position).isSelected) monthlySpendCard.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#fcd14b"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing you are missing click listener :

```
    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
       // do you stuff here
    }
    });

   ((ViewPager)container).addView(view, 0)
```

Also inside instantiateItem() make int position as final.